# Despues de igualado de cero, ¿cómo volver al valor original de la variable?

Tags: java, condiciones

Tengo una variable `ySpeed = 2` la cual igualo a 0 dentro del primer if. ¿Como puedo recuperar el valor original de dicha variable, para q en el segundo if vuelva a ser 2?

```
public void moveAlice() {
    y1+=ySpeed;
    y2+=ySpeed;
    y3+=ySpeed;
    float ySpeedAux = ySpeed;
    println(ySpeedAux);
    if (y3 >= height - mar) { //Boolean Expression
        ySpeed=0;
        x1+=xSpeed;
        x2+=xSpeed;
        x3+=xSpeed;
    }
    if (x2 >= width - mar) { //Boolean Expression
        xSpeed= 0;
        ySpeed= ySpeedAux;
        y1-=ySpeed;
        y2-=ySpeed;
        y3-=ySpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: puedes guardar una variable con el valor original, `prevSpeed` o `defaultSpeed`

Comment: ya que tienes muchas asignaciones (9), te recomiendo poner `+=`  => `y1+=ySpeed;` para que no haya tanto codigo redundante.

Comment: `float ySpeedAux = ySpeed;` ¿tu variable es del tipo `float`o del tipo `int`?

Answer (score 0):

Usa otra variable y la reasignas al empezar el segundo `if`

```
public void moveAlice(){
    y1=y1+ySpeed;
    y2=y2+ySpeed;
    y3=y3+ySpeed;

    int ySpeedAux = ySpeed;

    if(y3 >= height - mar){  //Boolean Expression
        ySpeed= 0;

        x1=x1+xSpeed;  
        x2=x2+xSpeed;
        x3=x3+xSpeed;
    }

    if(x2 >= width - mar){  //Boolean Expression
         xSpeed= 0;

         ySpeed = ySpeeedAux;
         y1=y1-ySpeed;
         y2=y2-ySpeed;
         y3=y3-ySpeed;
     }
```

<sub>**Nota**: He asumido que tu varialbe ySpeed es de tipo int, si es de otro cambialo al crear ySpeedAux</sub>

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52307/discussion-on-answer-by-lithorell-despues-de-igualado-de-cero-como-volver-al-v).

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar declarando tu variable como global en lugar de como local, ya que como te mencionaba una posible falla podría ser que no entre inmediatamente en tus dos if y por lo tanto cuando entra al 2 siempre está en 0. intenta declarando tu variable

```
int ySpeedAux = 0;
```

y dentro de tu método quedaría:

```
ySpeedAux = ySpeed;
```

Comment: pues pense q asi si lo haria pero no nada sigue igual

Comment: pon también el método o la parte donde utilizas ese método, siento que el error debe estar ahí